# Can I un-install Windows 10 from my HP elite book which comes with pre-installed *Operating system : Windows 10 Pro 64 and install on Virtual Machine?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu

I have a HP elite book which comes with  pre-installed *Operating system : Windows 10 Pro 64.
I want to uninstall this and install Ubuntu. Next, I want to put that Windows 10 pro 64 on Virtual box.
How can I do so? Is it product key based or OEM based. What are the steps to install the Windows10 on virtual box without losing the genuineness of Windows 10.

Comment: That is not likely to work well because Windows 10 will become activated twice on the same physical box and one or the other will become un-activated. You would need to back up all your data, format, install a new OS, VBOX, and then install Windows 10 as a VM. You may need to call Microsoft Sales Support to activate it.

Comment: You have an OEM license

Comment: OEM license cannot be move to different hardware, it will never activate.